# How to customize regular expression which let user can input number from zero to nine?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have below regular expression for email validation but I want to customize this regular for user can input number from zero to nine.

**Example:** heng18374sopheak@yahoo.com, 12948sopheak@yahoo.com, sopheak876@gmail.com

Here is email validation which let user input character only can't input number

This is Email validation Regular Expression which avoid user input number (0-9)
But I want my user can input that number(0-9).So How could I customize this below regular expression?

```
/(^[a-z]([a-z_\.]*)@([a-z_\.]*)([.][a-z]{3})$)|(^[a-z]([a-z_\.]*)@([a-z_\.]*)(\.[a-z]{3})(\.[a-z]{2})*$)/i
```

But I want to customize those code which let user could input number from zero to nine.

Thanks for help

Comment: I've already done it but it can't input number? mean that my email input can input only character can't input number (0-9) so I want to edit this Regexp which let user can input number

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following. Do you want the user to input an email INCLUDING digits 0 to 9 or do you want a field that can receive only digits 0 to 9 as input?

Comment: I want my user can input bother character and number example:
heng1209487sopheak@yahoo.com

Comment: add a-z0-9 everywhere you encounter a-z and you'll be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(^[a-z-0-9]([a-z_\.0-9]*)@([a-z_\.]*)([.][a-z]{3})$)|(^[a-z]([a-z_\.]*)@([a-z_\.]*)(\.[a-z]{3})(\.[a-z]{2})*$)/i
```

Simply add `0-9` to your pattern.

Comment: Yes this in work I try to insert it but i don't know where now I know

Answer (score 1):

hengsopheak

below code should work

```js
function evaluateMailRegularExp(emailInput){
   var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
 if(!$(emailInput).val().match(mailformat))  
 {  
  alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");  
  $(emailInput).val("");
  return false;   
 }  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
email : <input typr='text'  onblur=evaluateMailRegularExp(this)></input>
```

Comment: I user jquery validation as below

jQuery.validator.addMethod("email_valide", function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /(^[a-z]([a-z_\.0-9]*)@([a-z_\.]*)([.][a-z]{3})$)|(^[a-z]([a-z_\.]*)@([a-z_\.]*)(\.[a-z]{3})(\.[a-z]{2})*$)/i.test(value);
        }, ' 

It is wonderful work